# Regex not matches float values and '1-length non-digit'

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I have a string like

```
some_string = """
15.10.2020 102000 sometext 11112 
16.11.2020 120888.89 sometext 22222
18.09.2020 1 fjjfjf sometext 
15.12.2020 109555.55 sometext 22222
"""
```

I should have an output like this

```
15.10.2020 102000
16.11.2020 120888.89
18.09.2020 1
15.12.2020 109555.55
```

I tried to use this method but regex not matched  '1-length non-digit'

```
re.findall("\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s\d+\.{0,1}\d", some_string)
but had output
['15.10.2020 102000', '16.11.2020 120888.8', '15.12.2020 109555.5']
```

Then I tried to use change it like this

```
re.findall("\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s\d+\.{0,1}\D", some_string)
#in this case regex matched '1-length as digit' but not as a float
['15.10.2020 102000 ',
 '16.11.2020 120888.',
 '18.09.2020 5 ',
 '15.12.2020 109555.']
```

Could you help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Your regex to match the number is wrong as it requires at least two digits. Try `re.findall("\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s\d+(?:\.\d+)?", some_string)` or any of the other methods in the duplicate

Comment: No worries - I'm glad it was helpful